plotting 3d ellipses using R plotly
I'm having issues with plotly: essentially, I've been plotting PCA data and I need to plot them in 3D. Hence, plotly which supports that. I can plot the scores without any issues, the problem is when I try to overlap the ellipses around it to better identify the classes. Whatever I do, they never fit.
These are the two matrixes with some dummy loadings, the true PCA is computed with other methods I'm gonna skip over because it's not the issue.

PC1 <- c(1.43, 1.20, 0.48, 0.95, -2.76, -2.53, 2.38, 6.37)
PC2 <- c (-1.46, -2.85, -2.08, -2.08, -1.50, -2.15, 0.87, -4.64)
PC3 <- c (0.08, 5.37, 1.39, 2.74, 0.06, 1.95, 0.90, -0.18)

CA <- data.frame(PC1, PC2, PC3)

PC1 <- c(40.12, 19.01, 20.63, 20.50, 30.39, 10.46, 9.07)
PC2 <- c(-2.47, -2.04, -0.46, -2.37, -0.39, 0.97, 0.15)
PC3 <- c(1.27, 1.75, 0.53, 1.16, 0.44, 1.79, -0.76)
CB <- data.frame(PC1, PC2, PC3) 

library(plotly)
library(rgl)

CA <- as.matrix(CA)
CB <- as.matrix(CB)

ellipseA <- ellipse3d(cov(CA))
ellipseB <- ellipse3d(cov(CB))

fig <- plot_ly()%>%
  add_trace(data = CA, x = CA[,1], y = CA[,2], z = CA[,3],
            type = "scatter3d", mode = 'markers', marker = list(size = 3), 
            text = rownames(CA))%>%

  add_trace(x=ellipseA$vb [1,], y=ellipseA$vb [2,], z=ellipseA$vb [3,], 
            type='mesh3d', alphahull = 0, opacity = 0.2)%>%


  add_trace(data = CB, x = CB[,1], y = CB[,2], z = CB[,3],
          type = "scatter3d", mode = 'markers', marker = list(size = 3), 
          text = rownames(CB))%>%
  add_trace(x=ellipseB$vb [1,], y=ellipseB$vb [2,], z=ellipseB$vb [3,], 
            type='mesh3d', alphahull = 0, opacity = 0.2)

fig


the code works, in the sense that it plots a 3d scatter plot and then overlaps with two ellipses. These ellipses are nowhere near close to fit the data because they are centered on c(0,0,0) which is not the case for these data.
I also need to figure out how to change ellipses color, in order to match the color of the scatter plot but that's a separate issue.
So far I've tried to twink the code, I also tried computing the ellipses separately with

fit <- lm(PC2 ~ PC3 + PC4, CA)


for example and then plotting said ellipses, but it does nothing worthy

You write the code works … not for me, I get from both ellipse3d(): the leading minor of order 2 is not positive.

It keeps working for me. But try now I did a minor edit to the code

Now that error is gone.

Most likely you need to add the argument  center = c(x,y,z)  to the ellipse3d call.   So track down the (x,y,z) coordinates you want to center each ellipsoid on.

@CarlWitthoft's suggestion is on point.  One other thing:  it's not safe to assume that ellipseA$vb [1,] is the x coordinate (and similarly for y and z) because vb is stored in homogeneous coordinates. You should compute asEuclidean2(ellipseA$vb) and then use the rows of the result.  In this example you get the same coordinates, but that's not always true.

Expanding on CarlWitthoft's suggestion: You could use the mean of the data as the ellipsoid's center, e. g.
ellipseA <- ellipse3d(cov(CA), centre=apply(CA, 2, mean))


I also need to figure out how to change ellipses color, in order to match the color of the scatter plot…

I use vertexcolor = rep("#1f77b4", ncol(ellipseA$vb)) and vertexcolor = rep("#2ca02c", ncol(ellipseB$vb)) respectively as additional arguments in the two ellipsoid's add_trace calls.
